# Arbitrary Relationship to Another Django Model's Fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to build a notification system that can trigger based on a user-defined threshold in *any* field in another model.  A `Notification` model would save the user's notification preferences of the threshold and the field the threshold relates to in the other model called `Report`.  The challenge here is figuring out how to save the `Report` *field name* so that `Notification` knows which field the threshold relates to.  Ideally this would be something like a `ForeignKey` relationship, except it saves the external model's field name rather than its instance.  My idea is to make a model for storing the notification preference, but I don't know how to save the user's choice of the other field's model:

```
class Report(models.model):
    a = models.FloatField()
    b = models.FloatField()
    c = models.FloatField()

class Notification(models.model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    threshold = models.FloatField(). # for example, Report.a > 30 triggers this notification, but could also be Report.b
    threshold_field = ???  # this has to be a relationship to any field available in Report model (e.g. Report.a, Report.b, etc)
```

I know you can do `ForeignKey` relationships to *pre-defined* field with the `to_field` argument, but this option has to be *any* field in `Report`.  My idea is to just save `threshold_field` as a `CharField` and then use Python's `getattr` function when retrieving the `Report` data, but this isn't clean and could break if the field names in `Report` were to change.  There might be an option to override the `save` method, but I haven't found a way for that to work.

Comment: To handle field name changes for your idea it may be possible to listen to the post_migrate signal and detect/handle those changes in the `plan` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate, as you say it may not be very "clean" though

Comment: Typically this means that you should *linearize*: create a model like `ReportField`, and then make a `ForeignKey` from `Notification` to `ReportField` instead.

Comment: Would using a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) for your `threshold_field` help?  You could get the field names of `Report` at runtime using [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-a-single-field-instance-of-a-model-by-name), and query your JSONField as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree, this would be the best approach and something I thought about.  However, in production, `Report` has something like 30 FloatFields and each user typically retrieves them in batches of ~300.  This would cause a significant feedback in database lookups.

Comment: @Scott: typically if you need these, you can use `Report.objects.prefetch_related('reportfield_set')` to load all the related `ReportField` objects in bulk in one extra query, so this normally has not much impact performancewise.